# BCD 7447 powered by 7805 drops voltage

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, 7805

I am trying to use a BCD converter 7447 to display numbers on a seven segment display. Even before I apply any inputs or outputs, I observe that the VCC voltage of the 7447 drops (which is powered by a 7805 voltage regulator). The voltage drops to around 3V. I need this voltage to power up other ICs so can't afford it to go so low. I am unsure why is the voltage dropping so drastically. I have done some debugging and found the the 7447 is drawing just 7mA from the 7805 while the voltage is dropped to approximately 3V. I tried putting a resistor that draws 50mA and that only caused the voltage to drop to 4.85V. I am really confused why is the voltage dropping so much. I encourage the maker community to share their thoughts. I am stuck on this for the last two days.

ps. the input power supply to the 7805 is a 12V adapter capable of delivering 1A. It's output remained stable at 12V throughout all experimentation.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Have you used the recommended decoupling capacitors close to the 7805?

Comment: Please include a schematic. Did you connect the 7805 correctly? Are you measuring the supply voltage at the output of the 7805 or at the 7447s?

Comment: Hi Usman! this is really impossible to answer without knowing the schematic of exactly what you've built, I'm afraid – could you add that to your question? Also, details on where you measured (i.e. between which points) voltages and where (i.e. in between which nodes) current might help!

Comment: Thanks for your immense help guys. Let me add a schematic as you have suggested.

Comment: @Transistor, I haven't added any decoupling capacitors. I have used 7805 earlier and apparently it works just fine without them. What values should I add there are a few different schematics circulating online?

Comment: @StarCat, I just included a schematic to make it a little more clear. Thanks for the suggestion.

I have measured it at the Vcc of 7447. Does it matter though? They are connected by a smaller jumper wire.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MarcusMüller. I just added a schematic.

Comment: you really need to ALWAYS add decoupling caps, both at input and output of regulator, and on any ICs that are powered by it. Note that, although you are looking at the voltage with (presumably) a DMM, there might well be significant oscillation when you don't add caps. This will make measured voltage look odd, and will not be detectable without a scope. ALWAYS add decoupling, it can save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks @danmcb. Let me try it out and report back to you guys.

Comment: And don't leave input pins floating. I don't know this IC, but some don't like that at all. Tie them all to a reference (e.g. A..D to zero, the control pins to whatever level makes sense).

Comment: Sounds like the ammeter connections are bad, high resistance, or there is some connection fault. Unless the 7805 is stinky hot, in which case there is some other load drawing too much current.

Comment: Use the capacitors recommended for your 7805 or at a minimum add 100 nF on the input and output. When omitting decoupling capacitors ask yourself, "What do I know about these chips that the manufacturers don't know?" They recommend them for a reason - and in this case probably to prevent oscillation.

Comment: once you add a 7seg display (with resistors of course) the current consumption will rise and the 7805 will start to get a bit hotter. Add another digit, hotter still. Anticipate your current consumption and calculate how hot your 7805 will get before you find out the hard way. Even at 50mA, the 7805 might get hotter by around 20C at a rough guess. You might want to choose a 5V power supply or a switching regulator rather than your 7805.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Kartman.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone who commented and pointed in the right direction specially @Transistor. The problem was resolved by adding decoupling capacitors at input and output.